# Image Button to new Activity: Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to link my image to a new activity, I tried multiple of codes and solution online but I am having an error.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ImageButton myImageButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   myImageButton  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.APZ);
    myImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentLoadActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,APZ.class);
            startActivity(intentLoadActivity);
        }
    });
}
```

}

My problem is the ID I have set in the image is having an error, see the screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkMC1.jpg

Activity_main.XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Astoria Hotels and Resorts"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:columnCount="2"
        >

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25pt"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/APZ"
                    android:layout_width="123dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/astoria_plaza___project_logo___primary_lockup__small_" />

                <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Astoria Plaza"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25pt"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="123dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/agb_transparent" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Astoria Greenbelt"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="123dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/astoria_current_transparent" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Astoria Current"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="123dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ab1_transparent" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Astoria Boracay"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="123dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/abh___transparent" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Astoria Bohol"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Help please thanks!

Comment: share your `R.layout.activity_main` and  do you have another activity named `APZ`?

Comment: I've added my main activity xml codes

Comment: In xml you have ImageView, but in java you are using ImageButton? try using ImageView instead of ImageButton in java

Answer (score 0):

You are using ImageButton in java. If you want to use it replace ImageView with ImageButton in your layout.xml